# Activities opened with startActivityForResult not appearing in Recent Screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recents

I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html) guide to show my activity in Recent Screen like a separate task.
I've added this flag to open my activity in a new task:

```
newDocumentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

When I start an activity using `startActivityForResut` the new activity is not opened as a separate task. 
However, if I start an activity using `startActivity` it is opening in a new task.
Is this is the default behavior? or am I missing something?

Comment: Its default behavior, You can modify this behavior with FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS.

Comment: Oh. Let me try if this works.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK):

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

So I guess if you're asking for a result, android forces you to stay in the same task.